# how to disable web security in chrome using playwright

Tags: google-chrome, configuration, playwright, disable, websecurity

Use the launchOptions to set the browser launch configurations and pass the object to the browser instance.

```
var launchOptions = new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
 {
     Headless = false,
     Args = new[] { "--disable-web-security" }
 };

browser = await browserType.LaunchAsync(launchOptions);
```

Comment: Please tag with the appropriate language. Are you using Java?

Answer (score 1):

from playwright.config.ts use the below config,

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        launchOptions: {
          args: ['--disable-web-security'],
        }
      },
    }
  ]
}
```